# decode wordpress theme php file

Tags: php, wordpress, deobfuscation

[Here](http://pastebin.com/KRxi3gUN) is the code which is encoded,

I [tried](https://idecode.eu/) and paid `$4` for weekly plan and get the decoded file but when I paste it in the theme file then it doesn't work. Looks like it decode but some bugs makes the theme to show white screen of death.

I have tried even `ioncube_priv8_decoder_v1` to decode and its decoded file also not working with the theme. Can some body help please ?

Comment: That's not ioncube, it's just obfuscated PHP.  Not hard to decode, just time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one wasn't that difficult...here is some code to get you started:

```
<?php

$code = file_get_contents('/tmp/theme.php'); // read encoded script to string

$code = str_replace(';', ";\n", $code); // break statements onto individual lines

// replace hex encoded " (\x22) with \"
$code = preg_replace_callback('/\\\x22/i', function($match) {
    return '\"';
}, $code);

// hex decode encoded characters
$code = preg_replace_callback('/\\\x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/i', function($match) {
    return chr(hexdec($match[1]));
}, $code);

echo $code; // it's a start!

file_put_contents('/tmp/decoded.php', $code);
```

Next things to do would be load it in an IDE and format it so it's easier to read and properly indented, then if you wish you can start renaming obfuscated variables to something more meaningful; but as it stands the decoded output functions just as the encoded one does.

Hope that helps & good luck.

EDIT: [Here](http://pastebin.com/1uPX68Rt) it is decoded and formatted.  The paste never expires.  I hope you can accept my answer.

Disclaimer: Their faq states:

> Our customers have full liberty to use all our WordPress themes that
>   are licensed under the GNU general public license on any number of
>   websites with personal use limitation.

I assume all the themes are GPL licensed and are therefore free from restrictions such as modification or redistribution under the terms of the GNU GPL license.

Comment: Yes. I tried some services an batch files to decode but didn't work. Your decoded file worked. Thanks a millions. Answer accepted